# spring poller executer channel implementation

Tags: spring-integration

After my poller fetches data from DB, I am calling an external service.
After getting response from that service, I want to do call another systems in a separate thread. Means, after getting response, my poller should take another record and send.In addition **calling other systems should work in parallel**.

For this I used a direct channel for receiving the data from DB. Used a service activator for sending request to external service. The response is passed to an executer channel.can anyone please tell me whether the below configuration is correct for the scenario ?

For clarity I am sharing the poller.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
 xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:int-jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
 xmlns:stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream-4.1.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc/spring-integration-jdbc-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.1.xsd">

 <!-- <import resource="persistence-config.xml" /> <int:channel id="inchannel"> 
  </int:channel> <int:channel id="outchannel"> <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor"/> 
  </int:channel> <task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="2"/> <bean id="poller" 
  class="main.java.com.as.poller.PollerService" /> <int:service-activator input-channel="inchannel" 
  output-channel="outchannel" ref="poller" method="sendMessage" /> -->


 <int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="dataChannel"
  query="select loyalty_id, process_id,mobile_uid from TBL_RECEIPT where r_cre_time=(select min(r_cre_time) from TBL_RECEIPT where receipt_status=0)"
  data-source="dataSource" max-rows-per-poll="1"
  update="update TBL_RECEIPT set receipt_status=11 where loyalty_id in (:loyalty_id)">
  <int:poller fixed-rate="5000">
  </int:poller>
 </int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>


 <bean id="poller" class="main.java.com.as.poller.PollerService" />
 
 <int:channel id="executerchannel">
 <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor"/> 
  </int:channel>
  
 <task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="20"/>
 
 <int:service-activator input-channel="dataChannel"
  output-channel="executerchannel" ref="poller" method="processMessage" />
  
  <int:service-activator input-channel="executerchannel" ref="poller" method="processTpg">
  </int:service-activator>
  
  <stream:stdout-channel-adapter id="executerchannel"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; it's not correct (it is almost correct).

```
<stream:stdout-channel-adapter id="executerchannel"/>
```

this overrides your executor channel definition (an outbound adapter with no `channel` attribute creates a channel with that id).

You will end up with a simple direct channel with 2 subscribers (stdout and your service activator) - they will get alternate messages.

I am not sure why you added that element; remove it or subscribe it to some other channel.

If you want it to go to both places; change the channel to a `<publish-subscribe-channel/>` with an executor.

Comment: I added it for logging purpose only.Just to see what is there in executer channel.All i want is my executer channel to actually function as an executer channel.<int:service-activator input-channel="executerchannel" ref="poller" method="processTpg">
  </int:service-activator> .Will this do the purpose ???  i just want the method processTpg to receive the data from executer channel.

Comment: Yes; it will do as you say; Just remove the stdout adapter - consider using a wire tap to log the channel contents.